# Using comboBox with for ()

Tags: c#, for-loop, combobox, switch-statement

I have a school project and I was wondering how I should use a for-loop with this:

```
        for (int x = 1; x <= 12; x++)
        {
            switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "Mass(m)":
                mass = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                break;
        ...
```

I have 12 comboboxes therefore "x <= 12;", and I want to scan them for their SelectedItem (which I have about 20 of), can I change the 1 in comboBox1 and textBox1 to the x from the for-loop in any way?
Sincerely, some C# n00b.
Thanks.

Edit:

Project Idea: Make a program that calculates dif. physics units by choosing the unit (ex mass) and then type its value in a textbox. (combobox1 with textbox1, etc) then use switch-case inside of a for-loop that checks the selected item of ex. combobox1 and if it is mass it puts the values from textbox1 into my mass variable. Then with the for-loop it will easier search and put values in the right places.

I want to use the for loop as an easier way to search, like switching out ex. comboBox1's 1 with the for-loops variable x, and the same thing for the textBoxes.

Comment: I don't like this approach. You should get all of the comboboxes and use them in a `foreach`-loop, so you can get the values of every combobox.

Comment: To answer your question, yes you could do that but it would most likely involve reflection which isn't newbie friendly (in my opinion). Depending on what your goal is here there may be other approaches. If you really want to use a for loop it would probably be easier to create `UserControls` for each `ComboBox`/`TextBox` pair and loop through those. Or you could create a function from your `switch` statement then manually pass in the pairs 12 times. Or you could add the pairs to a dictionary or list

Answer (score 0):

So if it's just for a school project you can do it like this...

Create a List of your ComboBoxes and then use x as index:

```
List<ComboBox>myComboBoxList=new List<ComboBox>();
            myComboBoxList.Add(comboBox1);
            myComboBoxList.Add(comboBox2);
            //...add all your comboBoxes

            //and then...

            for (int x = 0; x < myComboBoxList.Length; x++)
            {
                switch (myComboBoxList[x].SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    case "Mass(m)":
                        mass = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                        break;
```